# Same Milliseconds values coming for different dates

Tags: android, calendar, milliseconds

I store my values in database by converting the date value in milliseconds,so to get the latest date on top by using order by desc query. The order is coming as required but if i enter date 02/01/2016 and 01/30/2016 both are storing same milliseconds value.

```
String date = "02/01/2016";
                        String month = date.substring(0, 2);
                        String day = date.substring(3, 5);
                        String year = date.substring(6, 10);
                        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c1.set(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month), Integer.parseInt(day));
                        long left = c1.getTimeInMillis();
```

After debugging i got the following milliseconds values
02/01/2016----61414914600000
 and 01/30/2016----61414914600000

Anybody knows why this happening?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int) : "month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January."

Comment: I just tried your code and am getting the correct result. Perhaps something else is wrong. And yes months start from 0 index.

Comment: ok you mean i should subtract one from the month value?

Comment: jyotman are u getting different values for the dates which i mentioned?

Comment: I got left = 1456836047682 which is Tue Mar 01 2016 12:40:47 UTC

Comment: Matt after subtracting 1 from month still the same issue

Comment: Jyotman please check for 02/01/2016 and 01/30/2016 values.

Comment: Have you also taken into account that `Calendar` is mutable? If you set the time twice then the first timestamp will get lost, and you observe the last timestamp twice. Make sure that you use two different instances of `Calendar`.

Comment: Meno thanks for this information but i used only single calendar instance

Answer (score 0):

Using SimpleDateFormat value I am getting different milliseconds value:

```
 Date date;
        String dtStart = "02/01/2016";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        try {
            date = format.parse(dtStart);
            long timeMills=date.getTime();
            System.out.println("Date ->" + date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your initial code and it functions almost as expected. A few points:

- You mention millisecond 61414914600000. That's not correct because it's 1900 years into the future:
  http://currentmillis.com/?61414914600000
- I'm pretty sure you got that number from a `Date` object, not from a `Calendar`: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(int, int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(int,%20int,%20int))
- As Mat said the month is zero-based for `Calendar` and the line where you call the setter should subtract 1:

  `c1.set(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month) - 1, Integer.parseInt(day));`
- You answered your own question with another snippet of code but `Date` is deprecated, `Calendar` should be used instead. Your original code in the initial post was essentially correct (except the zero-based month). You should make sure that you know where your output is coming from and / or that you don't forget to build the code before running it.

Comment: Thanks Teo for your information, but tell me exactly what should i use if date is deprecated and with calendar instance i am getting same values?

Comment: Calendar is the way to go. I ran the code for both dates and got 2 different numbers.

Comment: Used my code snippet? bcz it gave me same result for two diferent dates

Comment: Yes i used your snippet which i put in a method. I used this code:  public static void main(String[] args) {
  printMillis("01/30/2016");
  printMillis("02/01/2016");
 }
 
 public static void printMillis(String date){
  String month = date.substring(0, 2);
        String day = date.substring(3, 5);
        String year = date.substring(6, 10);
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.set(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month) - 1, Integer.parseInt(day));
        long left = c1.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println(left);
 }